# Linux: Get CPU usage over past n minutes

Tags: linux, bash, cpu-usage

I want a script to tell me the average CPU usage over the past 5 minutes (and repeat every 5 minutes, likely as a cron job).

`/proc/stat` just has counters since system start, and I want to avoid developing a full program to parse and sample that. `top` seems to just report usage over the moment (second?) before it displays/writes the table.

sysstat/sar looks promising, but looks like I'll always loose the midnight value looking at what `sar -u` gives me...

Comment: the things I mentioned, /proc/stat, top, sar. I am not asking for the code (like I said, I don't really want custom/new code for this task), I am looking for an existing Linux utility / command line to get CPU usage info over a time period that works accross day boundaries etc (potentially along the lines of `sar -u`, but that misses the midnight value it seems...)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sar` for that. For example `sar 300` will be printing out the average CPU usage for the 5 minute periods.

```
~]# sar 300
Linux xxxxx....

10:40:02 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
10:45:02 AM     all     69.57      0.00      4.69      0.04      0.00     25.70
10:50:02 AM     all     68.99      0.00      4.61      0.07      0.00     26.33
10:55:02 AM     all     68.98      0.00      4.88      0.05      0.00     26.09
```

Comment: does that work at just after 00:00:00 ? in my testing it never seemed to, because it would not combine the previous days data file fully? maybe some extra steps / tools / config?

Answer (score 6):

You want to look at `/proc/loadavg`. The first three fields are the one-minute, five-minute, and fifteen-minute load averages. For a built-in utility, look at the `uptime` command.